# Why does $10^{18} \pmod{10^9 + 7} \equiv 49$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

To provide some context is where I got this question:

https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/math/number-theory/basic-number-theory-1/tutorial/

Comment: Because $x^2-49$ is divisible by $x+7$. Apply to $x=10^{9}$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews +1, so clever

Answer (score 4):

$$10^{18}-49=(10^9-7)(10^9+7),$$
which says that our statement is true.

Answer (score 3):

As said by Thomas,

$$10^{18}-49=(10^9)^2-7^2$$
$$=(10^9+7)(10^9-7) $$

thus
$$10^9+7 | 10^{18}-49$$

and
$$10^{18}\equiv 49 \pmod{10^9+7}$$

Comment: Why there is no blue color for new upvotes.